# expected audio sample rate doesn't match actual?

Tags: bash, shell, audio, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am trying to use pocket sphinx to transcribe audio files.

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile 116-288045-0005.flac.wav
```

but I am getting the errors:

```
ERROR: "continuous.c", line 136: Input audio file has sample rate [44100],
       but decoder expects [16000]
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 165: Failed to process file '116-288045-0005.flac.wav'
       due to format mismatch.
```

Here's one of the audio files I need to transcribe: [Download from GitHub](https://github.com/theonlygusti/files/raw/master/116-288045-0000.flac.wav)

Eventually I will batch-transcribe over 5 hours of audio files like these, currently they all throw the same error.

Here's some stats of the same file I'm trying to transcribe:

```
$ soxi 116-288045-0000.flac.wav

Input File     : '116-288045-0000.flac.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:10.65 = 469665 samples = 798.75 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 939k
Bit Rate       : 706k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

There might be a problem with some of this file's configuration, I've done some pre-processing to merge it with mp3s, convert from flac to wav, among others.

What's the easiest way now for me to get the transcription working?

Is it possible without re-sampling the files back down to 16kHz. Originally the flac files had a sample-rate of 16kHz, but I had to merge them with 44.1kHz mp3 files. Therefore there's some high-frequency information in them now that may be lost if resampled to 16k.

Answer (score 2):

Resample the audio to `16000` samples then try again.

You can resample like this
`sox file.wav -r 16000 file-16000.wav`

Comment: But that gets rid of information. What happened was the `.flac` files were originally 16000Hz, but I had to merge them with 44.1kHz mp3 files. Therefore there's some high-frequency information in there that may be lost if resampled to 16k

Comment: How can I do it without resampling to 16kHz?

Comment: Another option might be to modify the config file and change the default sampling rate for decoder. The option name in config is `-samprate`

Comment: Sorry, I don't totally understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Pocketsphinx does not use information above 16khz anyway so you can safely resample. It is the easiest solution.